# Loading an element. After that loading another element into the loaded element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i built a website where my frame, with the main menue and the banner, is always exisiting.

I created a div element, in which i can load everything i want dynamically.

But now i have a problem. If somebody clicks a link, i want to load a html document into my div-frame. When this has been done, a another html document should be loaded into a part of the new loaded html document.

The rask is now, to check when the first div element has been loaded and load something into this element.

**An Example:**

```
$("#examplelink").click(function() 
{

$("#mainsite").load("firstlowerside.html");

$("#firstlowerside_div").load("secondlowerside.html");

});
```

Javascript is ignoring the command line:
    $("#firstlowerside_div").load("secondlowerside.html")
, because the "firstlowerside.html" isnt already exisiting at this thime.

Can somebody tell my how i can check is the document has been loaded into my div and start executing the second command after this?

Answer (score 6):

[`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) has a complete callback parameter you can pass a function that will fire after the content is loaded.

```
$("#mainsite").load("firstlowerside.html", function(){
    $("#firstlowerside_div").load("secondlowerside.html");
});
```

Comment: you can always add more using the .done() callback on the Promise object as well.

Comment: Damn that was simple. Thank you :-)

Comment: @Derek I agree using `.done` would be better, but why do you mean "you can always add more" ?

Comment: @Derek Yeah nevermind, I get what you meant. Took me a second to realize :)